# How to call a function batchwise in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a function defined and I just want to know if it is possible to perform it batchwise. For instance,

```
def function():
    Some processes here
    return x

def forward():
    encode = self._encoding(embedded_premises,premises_lengths)
```

Now since, the encode will be 3D tensor, which will be `batch size, seq_length, hidden size` I want to perform `function()` batchwise and `return x` also batchwise.

Is there any other way than looping over all batches?

Comment: Can you add more details about `function`? Most of the operations in pytorch are batched already

Comment: @UmangGupta What do you want to know about `function`? Actually, I know that there are function like matrix multiplication as discussed here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/more-batch-matrix-operations/4340. The `function` is not in built if that helps. I have implemented my own custom function. For example, my `forward()` will have `batch size, len, hidden units` and I am planning to send the `len` in `function()` but since it will be tensor, `function()` needs to be applied batchwise.

Comment: If you are looking for some oracle that can convert any normal fn written for sample to batch.. then sorry no! It doesn't exist. So it depends on what operations are u doing inside batch. Most of the operation like conv, lstm etc operate on batches already.

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with pytorch functions inside your `function`, which you most likely are if you want your method to work with autograd, it *can* work batchwise. That means most pytorch operations respect or can be made to respect the first dimension as batch dimension (for instance convolutions, linear layers, etc). Sometimes it's more complex to express your operation such that it is both correct and fast, but in general pytorch is built with the assumption that operations will be used on batched data and it is made as simple as reasonably possible. If you have a more specific example of your `function`, please post it.